# Anyway to still have Google Play Store on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, tablet, nexus-7

I was curious as to if I installed Ubuntu on my Nexus 7 if I could still take advantage of the Google Play store. I have many games I bought that I would not like to just leave behind if I installed Ubuntu, examples being GTA III and Minecraft.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, none that I am aware of - while Ubuntu and Android both use Linux kernels, they are separate operating systems entirely, and software for one will not generally run on the other.

Comment: Okay. I'm afraid for now then I will have to stick to just using Android then. Is there anyway you could dualboot and have both OS's by chance?

Comment: Don't know the answer to that one - never even thought about dual-booting a mobile device.  You should Google it, and if that doesn't answer your question, ask it as a new Question here. =)

Comment: @Nick there is currently no way to dual boot yet, although it's shown to be something the community is very interested in, so I'd stay tuned in case someone figures it out soon.

Comment: Take a look at the following link, this was released by the community a few days ago http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2011403