# How can I run full the Android OS, including Google Play Store, on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, games, android

I want to play Android games on Ubuntu 18.04. Some games are linked to my Google account so I probably need to run the Play Games and Play Store.

Note that [similar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/239386/is-there-an-emulator-or-wine-type-environment-that-would-allow-use-of-android-ap) [questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1732/can-i-run-android-apps-on-ubuntu) [have](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221853/anyway-to-still-have-google-play-store-on-ubuntu) [been](https://askubuntu.com/questions/791753/how-can-i-play-google-playstore-games-on-ubuntu-14-04) posted here before but those posts are quite old and the main answers no longer seems to apply to 18.04 and current state of tech.

Comment: Actually, the answers with **Android x86** are still relevant; you can also try **Prime OS**. Both of these solutions require VM software, like Virtualbox or QEMU.

Comment: @ajgringo619 - I am sure there might be answers in those olds posts that might still be be relevant, but the top/main answers may not be relevant given their age. I made this comment to make it clear to the mods why my question is not a duplicate post.

Thanks for your suggestions. Any chance you could post them as answers below?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are (2) complete Android OS platforms that I've have good luck with:

- **Android x86** (https://www.android-x86.org/)
- **Prime OS** (https://www.primeos.in/)

I have only run these under a virtual environment (Virtualbox and QEMU), but they can be installed as a dual-boot. **Android x86** is more mature than **Prime OS**.

Now, if you want to run Android apps natively, there is **Anbox** (https://anbox.io/). It's harder to setup, and does not support Google Play out-of-the-box, but it looks promising.